# How to create a function to send messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have a `node.js` app that I have created a discord bot to interact with. I would like it so that if a particular event happens with my `node.js` app that it will send a message to a particular channel in my discord server.

This is my first time using `discord.js`. However, my thought was to create a function that I can call to send my messages. However, it would seem that I need to wait for my client to be ready first.

Alternatively, would I just have to instantiate a new client every time I want to send a message and wait for it to come available before I send the message I want?

I feel like there has to be a better way... Is there a clean way that I can set up this basic discord bot that I can just call a function to send a message from anywhere within my app?

Here is the code that I have now:

```
import { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } from "discord.js";
import { botToken, CHANNEL_ID } from "../../config.js";

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] }); // Create a new client instance

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
// We use 'c' for the event parameter to keep it separate from the already defined 'client'
client.once(Events.ClientReady, c => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID).send("Hello!");
});

// Log in to Discord with your client's token
client.login(botToken);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I would like it so that if a particular event happens with my node.js app that it will send a message to a particular channel in my discord server."*

It sounds like you're looking for webhooks. Webhooks are a way for an external source, such as your Node.js app, to send messages to a Discord channel without having to log in as a bot. Instead of using a Discord bot, you can use a webhook to send messages to a channel as if they were posted by a bot.

Using a webhook is simple; you just need to make an HTTP `POST` request to a URL provided by Discord, with the message you want to send in the body of the request. Discord will then post that message to the specified channel.

This is useful in cases where you want to receive notifications from your app in a Discord channel, or simply want to send messages to a channel without having to log in as a bot. It's a clean and efficient way to integrate your app with Discord.

Here is an example of a `sendMessage` function. It takes two arguments, `payload` and `webhookUrl`. If the `payload` is not a string, it is assumed to be an object that conforms to the Discord webhook format and will be used as is.

```js
function sendMessage(payload, webhookUrl) {
  const data = typeof payload === 'string' ? { content: payload } : payload;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(webhookUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          reject(new Error(`Could not send message: ${response.status}`));
        }
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

If you're using node.js v18+, you can use the built-in `fetch`, if not, you'll need to install a library like `node-fetch`, `axios`, or something else.

Here is an example how you could use it:

```js
// send a simple message
sendMessage('Hello from my app!', WEBHOOK_URL).catch((error) =>
  console.error(error),
);

// send a message, but change the username and the avatar
sendMessage(
  {
    content: 'Hello from my app!',
    avatar_url: 'https://i.imgur.com/KEungv8.png',
    username: 'Test Hook',
  },
  WEBHOOK_URL,
).catch((error) => console.error(error));

// send an embed and change the user again
sendMessage(
  {
    avatar_url: 'https://i.imgur.com/ofPowdD.png',
    username: 'Cattian Hook',
    embeds: [
      {
        title: 'Cats, cats, cats',
        color: 0xe7d747,
        thumbnail: {
          url: 'https://i.imgur.com/2bvab7y.jpeg',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  WEBHOOK_URL,
).catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

And here is the result:

[image]

If you're already using discord.js, you can use the [`WebhookClient`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/WebhookClient?scrollTo=send):

```js
import { WebhookClient } from 'discord.js';

const webhookClient = new WebhookClient({
  url: WEBHOOK_URL,
});

webhookClient.send({
  content: 'Discord.js webhook test',
  username: 'DJS Webhook',
  avatarURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/KEungv8.png',
});
```

To create a webhook, you'll need to go to your discord server settings and click on `APPS` => `Integrations`. Then click on the `Create Webhook` button. There you can select the channel where you want the messages to be sent.

Once the webhook is created, you can click the `Copy webhook URL` button and use that URL.

[image]
[image]